# Why did the Autobots sometimes need jetpacks to fly and sometimes they didn't?

Tags: transformers

In episode 1 of the Transformers G1 animated series, the Autobots arrive to fight the Decepticons over an oil platform by flying (without jetpacks).  Later, in episode 3, we see Optimus Prime asking another Autobot to give to him his jetpack, to catch the Decepticon spaceship which was leaving Earth. So I thought, ok, may be the Autobots need jetpacks to fly to high altitudes or something.

But then, in the episode "Dinobot island, part 2", we see Optimus Prime asking other Autobots to grab some jetpacks to go to Dinobot Island. And they get them, and go there by flying using jetpacks, at the end of the episode we see the Autobots flying together with the Dinobots, the Autobots use jetpacks for flying and the Dinobots don't use them and don't need them. Also oddly, there are several episodes where we see the Dinobots flying without a jetpack, but there is one where Swoop transports Snarl by air with his legs, like if Snarl wouldnt be able to fly. Also, I'm almost sure we see another episode where we see Wheeljack flying without a jetpack, probably that one where the Dinobots arrive to save the Autobots along with Wheeljack.

Why did the Autobots sometimes need jetpacks to fly and sometimes they didn't?

Comment: Because their continuity editor drinks during the day?

Comment: Some relevant comments in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55401/why-can-only-decepticons-fly-in-robot-mode - which seem to come down to continuity errors...

Comment: Jetpacks sold separately?